# Calling Msbuild from Php - Wrong Codepage and Culture

Tags: php, msbuild, character-encoding

I have a Php script that calls Msbuild via System:

```
<?php
system( "msbuild umlaut.proj" );
?>
```

This is the project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
  DefaultTargets="EchoUmlaut" 
  ToolsVersion="3.5">
  <Target Name="EchoUmlaut">
    <Message Text="Umlaute: Ä Ö Ü ä ö ü ß" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

When I call Msbuild directly from the command line the output of msbuild is in German (as excpected) and the umlauts come out OK (I chcp to 1252). But when I use php to call msbuild the umlauts are wrong, and the output of msbuild is changed to English. I wonder what I can do to prevent this.

```
C:\>chcp
Aktive Codepage: 1252.

C:\>msbuild umlaut.proj
Microsoft (R)-Buildmodul, Version 3.5.30729.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.3607]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Das Erstellen wurde am 13.04.2010 08:57:04 gestartet.
Projekt "D:\Cvsroot\projekte\e4elaui\v1.0\umlaut.proj" auf Knoten 0 (Standardziele).
  Umlaute: Ä Ö Ü ä ö ü ß
Die Erstellung von Projekt "D:\Cvsroot\projekte\e4elaui\v1.0\umlaut.proj" ist abgeschlossen (Standardziele).


Das Erstellen war erfolgreich.
    0 Warnung(en)
    0 Fehler

Vergangene Zeit 00:00:00

C:\>php call_from_php.php
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 3.5.30729.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.3607]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 13.04.2010 08:57:11.
Project "D:\Cvsroot\projekte\e4elaui\v1.0\umlaut.proj" on node 0 (default targets).
  Umlaute: Ž ™ š „ ”  á
Done Building Project "D:\Cvsroot\projekte\e4elaui\v1.0\umlaut.proj" (default targets).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the php script is not passing in some of the environment variables that the shell passes in. You will need to set them manually using putenv:

```
bool putenv  (  string $setting  );
```

copy them from the shell and paste them into the script before calling system.

Comment: That's what I thought too. Therefore I ran msbuild with the "/verbosity:diag" which lists all properties including the environment variables. Both lists are the same.